# Not able to Logout Properly

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, oauth-2.0

I have an application. 
**OnCreate** I create oauthservice object : and go dologin()

> oauthService = new OAuth2Service(this, config);

config has app client_id and client_secret. in dologin i clear tokens making all my local tokens null and call

> StartActivityForResult(oauthService.AuthorizationRequestIntent,
>   AUTHORIZATION_REQUEST_CODE);

this will callback to OnActivityResult and will try to create a token request

> AuthorizationResponse response =
>   AuthorizationResponse.FromIntent(data);
>                       OAuth2Exception ex = OAuth2Exception.FromIntent(data);

Now in UI, when you open the app it will open chrome and open up login page. user will  enter credentials and if successful, a token will be granted and user willl be redirected back to the app.
Now issue comes is at logout. When i click on logout i clear tokens and shared preferences

> ISharedPreferencesEditor sharedPreferencesEditor =
>   PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences(Android.App.Application.Context).Edit();
>               sharedPreferencesEditor.Remove(TokenStore.KeyAccessToken);
>               sharedPreferencesEditor.Clear();
>               sharedPreferencesEditor.Commit();
>               sharedPreferencesEditor.Apply();

and the app will be killed. But if the user opens the app again he'll be redirected to chrome. But it takes the data from cookies and redirects back to the my application, never asking for credentials. If after logout i manually delete all cookies and reopen app, it works fine and goes to login oage